# Java: Sorting an array from least to greatest

Tags: java, arrays

This is my first question on the site. I am in a CS class and part of one of my assignments involved sorting the scores column of an array from least to greatest and printing out the array in its new least-to-greatest form. I cannot seem to get the scores from the array to do so, for whatever reason, and I am very confused as to why it will not work. If any of you could help me, that would be awesome. Thanks! Here is the array I am working with. The two columns are the id (on the left) and the score (on the right):

```
365 265
222 223
306 262
003 559
004 560
203 224
113 243
208 242
213 229
115 257
302 242
223 230
001 599
311 256
323 245
321 245
123 253
104 239
002 513
112 239
207 228
325 246
116 246
218 243
110 238
```

And here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class RankingTestScoresDriver
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("ID     Score");
    File file = new File("prog408a.dat");
    int[] id = new int[24];
    int[] score = new int[24];
    try
    {
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(file);
        while (kbReader.hasNextInt())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
            {
                id[i] = kbReader.nextInt();
                score[i] = kbReader.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }

//From here down is the part which is giving me trouble.

    int max;
    max = score[0];
    int index;
    int maxScoreIndex = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 25; k++)
    {
    for (index = 0; index < score.length; index++)
    {
        if (score[index] > max)
        {
            max = score[index];
            maxScoreIndex = index;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxScoreIndex + "     " + max);
    score[maxScoreIndex] = ((-1)*(max));
    }
}
```

}

Currently it is producing this as the output:

ID     Score
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599
12     599

The final output should be the scores of the array but in least-to-greatest order.

Any help would be greatly appreciated in helping me fix the bit of code I am struggling on.

Comment: First thing to learn Java and JavaScript have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Second thing to learn is to **never** silently swallow exceptions - print them out

Comment: Well I would remove the tag, but someone made a useless edit so....

Comment: I do not understand your logic.  Why do you have a nested loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a class that implements `Comparable` to do it simple.

```
class Score implements Comparable<Score> {
    private int id, score;
    Score(int id, int score) {
        this.id = id;
        this.score = score;
    }

    @override
    public int compareTo(Score o) {
        return score - o.score;
    }
}
```

then after you create an array of `Score`, you can use `sort()` method.

```
Score[] scores = /* put data */
Arrays.sort(scores);
```

will work

Answer (score 1):

In the section where you are trying to sort, I'd recommend calling Arrays.sort() on your array like this:

```
Arrays.sort(score);
```

Once you have the array sorted, print out each element from the beginning using a loop of some kind:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    System.out.println(i + "     " + score[i]);
}
```

That should do the trick for you. If you don't need a fancy new sorting algorithm, just use one that's already coded for you :)

Comment: Daniel Pereira has mentioned bubble sort. A better implementation of bubble sort would be to start at the beginning of the array and follow the following steps: if the current value is larger than the next value in the array, swap them, and then move forward in the loop to the next index. if it's not bigger than the next value, just move to the next element and try swapping those. If you ever make a full pass through the array and don't swap, the array is sorted and you can stop. Make n-1 passes through the array where n is length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the array. Right now your code doesn't do it, it just keeps track of the biggest value.

I'm assuming you don't have to worry about execution time here. In other words, if the algorithm is going to take a long time to execute for a large input it doesn't matter to your professor.

There are many ways to sort an array. One way to do it called [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). It is not very effective but will do the trick for you, and it's probably what your professor wants for now.

The idea is pretty simple: you discover the lowest value you hold on the entire array and swap the value with your current position. Imagine you have the following array:

[2, 4, 3, 5, 1]

Your current index is `0`. You're going to go through the entire array to find the lowest value of them all. You will find out that the index 4, that holds the value `1` contains the lowest value. So you swap your current index (index `0`, value `2`). Now the array looks like this:

[1, 4, 3, 5, 2]

Now you move on to the next index, which is `1`. You don't need to look at index `0` anymore since you already found out he is the lowest value and now you want the second lowest value. You do the same thing you did before: find the lowest value from index 1 to index 4 and swap them. You're going to do it until you get to the last index, where, you can guess by now, it will always be the biggest value.

Start by making sure you get the first value right. Once you get it, then move to the loop that iterates through the other values.

Comment: Why write a sort algorithm yourself? I haven't done that in decades, pretty much never outside of class assignments...

Comment: The question mentions a Computer Science class, so I'm assuming using the language sort mechanism won't be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

**Working code :  sort a two-dimensional array on column values in java.**

Here we are using **overloaded sort method** in java.util.Arrays class which takes **two arguments** : the ***array to sort*** and a ***java.util.Comparator object***.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortArray {

    Integer array[][] = { { 365, 265 }, { 222, 223 }, { 306, 262 },
            { 003, 559 }, { 004, 560 }, { 203, 224 }, { 113, 243 },
            { 208, 242 }, { 213, 229 }, { 115, 257 }, { 302, 242 },
            { 223, 230 }, { 001, 599 }, { 311, 256 }, { 323, 245 },
            { 321, 245 }, { 123, 253 }, { 104, 239 }, { 002, 513 },
            { 112, 239 }, { 207, 228 }, { 325, 246 }, { 116, 246 },
            { 218, 243 }, { 110, 238 } };

    SortArray() {
        System.out.println("Before sorting");
        // show the contents of array
        displayArray();

        // sort array on score(second column)
        Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Integer[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer[] o1, Integer[] o2) {
                Integer v1 = o1[1];
                Integer v2 = o2[1];
                // reverse sort on quantity
                return v1.compareTo(v2);
            }
        });
        // display array after sort
        System.out.println("After sorting on score in ascending order");
        displayArray();

    }

    public void displayArray() {

        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(" Index \t\t score");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            Integer[] sorted = array[i];
            System.out.println(sorted[0] + "\t\t" + sorted[1]);
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SortArray();
    }

}
```

**Explanation**

A two dimensional array named array is created and initialized with default values. 
First column of the array consists of Index values and second column is its Score.
For sorting the array, sort method of java.util.Arrays is used which takes 2 arguments : the array to be sorted and a java.util.Comparator object.

We pass an anonymous Comparator object(anonymous object means an object which has no name and which is created at its place of use only).
As 2d array in java is an array of arrays, thus, for sorting a 2d array on a column, we have to sort an integer array, therefore the generic type of this Comparator object should be Integer[ ].

Inside Comparator object, we implement its compare method which takes two objects of Integer[ ] type. These Integer objects represent the arrays to be compared.
For sorting the array on second column(score), the values at index 1 of the Integer[ ] objects are retrieved and compared.

Also read about [Comparators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) and [sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a,
            Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Sorts the specified array of objects according to the order induced by the specified comparator. All elements in the array must be mutually comparable by the specified comparator (that is, c.compare(e1, e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the array).
This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.

The implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and descending order in its input array, and can take advantage of ascending and descending order in different parts of the the same input array. It is well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays: simply concatenate the arrays and sort the resulting array.

The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python ( TimSort). It uses techiques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474, January 1993.

Parameters:
a - the array to be sorted
c - the comparator to determine the order of the array. A null value indicates that the elements' natural ordering should be used.

Comment: Hi, I have provided a link  below the code that explains it all.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the explanation. Thank you for pointing out :)